How can I join objects in a specific order?
I'm using Blender 4.2 to create a mesh that I will later use in a VFX in Unreal Engine to spawn particles.
My worlflow from blender to the game engine is the following: I want to spawn particles along a complex mesh in the game, that would be too high-poly to sample in realtime (let's say here, the crescent shape of a blade). I'm thus creating a duplicate low-poly mesh to instanciate a bunch of individual triangles in the shape that I need.


This new triangle mesh is the one I'm actually sampling in the game-engine, spawning as many particles as there are triangles, each particle being spawned exactly at the center of each triangle.
This is a common workflow for VFX, often used to spawn particles in a sequence to follow a specific shape. In this example, I would want to spawn the particles along this crescent shape, bottom to top. To do so, I need the faces to have the correct ID, ranging from 0 at the bottom to 12 at the top.


As you can see here, the triangles seem to inherit their face IDs from the original mesh that was used to instantiate them, over which I have no control (with an offset based on which triangle I selected last). No matter how I choose to select then join the triangles together, I don't have any control over the face IDs order, except over the ID 0 which is always the active object.
My question is thus: is there a way to choose the order in which the faces will be joined? Or maybe a way to have control over the face IDs while creating the initial mesh? I'm used to this workflow in Maya (the face ID depends on the order of selection before combining the faces) and I would like to know if I'm missing something here. I feel like there  could be some workarounds, like creating a mesh from scratch by extruding vertices, which seems to create them in the right order, but I'm looking for something more versatile that would work with all kind of shapes I can create.
Sorry for this long text, I hope I managed to explain the context.
Thanks for your help!

I guess what you are looking for is in Edit mode, menu Mesh > Sort Elements .... It lets you change the IDs of the elements so they are in a given order. If you need a more complex order, for example ordering the IDs following a curve, then try a Geometry Node modifier with the Sort Elements node. The Sort Weight input defines the order.
